# Custom main loop in C# Remoting

Tags: c#, remoting, corba, .net-remoting, iiop

I'm using IIOP.NET to communicate with C++ in C#. Currently C++ calls can happen anytime, since C# Remoting Framework uses its own thread.

I don't want that.

Some other middleware gives me a callback, and I'm only allowed to execute the CORBA functions during this callback (and probably on the same stack, so simply synchronizing threads won't work).

So :

Is there a way to do something like that in C# Remoting :

```
while(1) {
    processPendingRequests();
}
```

Instead of `Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite)`? Or maybe is there another way?

Comment: Have you tried "while(true) { processPendingRequests(); }"?

Comment: processPendingRequests() is a name I just made up. The question was : what is the actual name of this function ?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. Nevermind my comment then...

Comment: You can create a task queue and put request there. The a new thread will consume the queue and make specific CORBA calls.

Comment: I thought about that. But this will require re-implementing all the marshalling/unmarshalling stuff already done by Corba. This also means that each new request will be unmarshalled, re-marshalled, and unmarshalled again. Finally, this ruins all the syncs Corba does for synchronous function calls...